# Python2.7 - Parse 1.csv, find match in # 2.csv then copy data from 2.csv and output

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Must be something I'm completely overlooking.

I'm trying to get this script

```
import csv

in_file = open("11pmTrend.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.DictReader(in_file, delimiter= ',')
out_file = open("11pm.csv", 'w')
out_file.write("Rank,Symbol,CurrentPrice\n")
check_file = open("11pmQuote.csv", 'r')
check = csv.DictReader(check_file, delimiter=',')

trend = set()
trend_sn = dict()
for row in reader:
    trend.add(row["Symbol"])
    trend_sn[row["Symbol"]] = row["Rank"]
    print(row["Symbol"])

stocknums = dict()
for row in check:
    stocknums[row["Sym"]] = row["Price"]
    print(row["Sym"])


for product in trend:
    ref = 0
    if product in stocknums:
        if(stocknums[product] > 0):
            ref = (row["Price"])


out_file.write(str(trend_sn[product]) + ',' + str(product) + ','+ str(ref)+ "\n")
```

To look at this file first 11pmTrend.csv (about 100 rows on avg), which contains Ranks and Stock/Crypto Symbols, and capture the Symbol, then

```
Rank,Symbol
15,BTC
12,TSLA
```

Open the second file 11pmQuote.csv (about 9000 rows on avg), which contains Symbols/Prices and grab the corresponding price and

```
Sym,Price
TSLA,302.25
BTC,7000.76
```

Output it into a third file 11pm.csv which should look like this:

```
Rank,Symbol,CurrentPrice
12,TSLA,302.25
15,BTC,7000.76
```

But instead, Im getting this:

```
Rank,Symbol,CurrentPrice
12,TSLA,7000.76
15,BTC,7000.76
```

It's grabbing the first row from the first file and then appending that price to both rows instead of iterating/looping and outputs the correct price to match for the second row.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referencing in

```
for product in trend:
    ref = 0
    if product in stocknums:
        if(stocknums[product] > 0):
            ref = (row["Price"])
```

in the last line row["Price"] which refers to the loop above it which is already done so row["Price"] would always give you the price of the last line.

So it should probably be:

```
for product in trend:
    ref = 0
    if product in stocknums:
        if(stocknums[product] > 0):
            ref = (stocknums[product])
```

because stocknums[product] = price

I'm actually not sure what you want to do in the last loop but I guess that the last line in your code (the "out_file.write") is also in this loop and you didn't provide a working code sample.

Comment: "out_file.write" is whats writing this: Rank,Symbol,CurrentPrice
12,TSLA,7000.76
15,BTC,7000.76...   So I want the script to loop through the entire Symbol list (example above as 11pmTrend.csv) and grab the stocks prices for each Symbol

Comment: You are neglecting the first part of my answer regarding row["Price"]. And yes, I know that it does output that. but it has to be in a loop, hasn't it? It isn't in your example, so it's not a working code sample.

Comment: Thats the part I was missing.. I had thought by stating it as ref = (row["Price"]) it would then pull that part in and of it self.. Didn't think that 'stocknums[product] = price' only, had thought it would also add the symbol a 2nd time.. Modified the code and it works now,,, Thank You Very, Very Much !!!

Comment: You are welcome, especially if you accept my answer to close the question.